# Why doesn't union distribution happen with T[number] where T is an ArrayLike?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types, conditional-types

In the example below ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFShAHsCA7AJgZygEEAnEgQxABkBLAawkQFds7s4B3bAPm6gF4oyANrYmAWwBGEEgF00mHASg1sAMxlQAogBsI4gFBQoAfm17xw2UagAuKNggA3GQG4DoSFABC5EigUsPEJSCmp6RhY2Th4+QRExKRl5DCDlVQ0Sc30bM119QKVCDM0AVRtjM1KrCrsHZxkbe0cXEncDAHoOqAABYHwAWgxIAGNgIbI4EgMRuGx8YCg1BHt4JGEABgAaKABGWTioTZ399y7e-qH0UfGZEimZuYWoST97X39jvYOBI+3v9xAA)), I expect `Foo<[0, 1]>` and `Bar<[0, 1]>` both resolve to `0[] | 1[]` because of the union distribution in conditional types. However, `Foo<[0, 1]>` is actually `(0 | 1)[]` and the compiler claims that the first `@ts-expect-error` directive is unused.

```js
type Foo<T extends ArrayLike<unknown>> = T[number] extends infer Elem
  ? Elem[]
  : never;
type Bar<T extends ArrayLike<unknown>> = T[number] extends infer Elem
  ? Elem extends infer U
    ? U[]
    : never
  : never;

// @ts-expect-error
const foo: Foo<[0, 1]> = [0, 1];
// @ts-expect-error
const bar: Bar<[0, 1]> = [0, 1];
```

I consulted the documentation and found [the following statement](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types);

> When conditional types act on ***a generic type***, they become *distributive* when given a union type. (emphasis on "a generic type" mine)

The only reason I can think of is that `Elem` is a generic type in the example but `T[number]` itself is not. I suspect this results in the conditional type not being distributive with `T[number]`, but am not sure if my guess is correct. Could someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distribution happens only over naked type parameters, meaning a single type parameter without any other type operation applied to it.

`T[number]` is not a naked type parameter, so no distribution. `Elem` is a naked type parameter in the second type, so distribution occurs.

Comment: So, my guess was correct. I've never heard of the term "naked type parameter", but found it in a [release note](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types). Thank you!

Comment: @yudai-nkt The terminology used to be in the old docs. Now they jusy say 'When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types